# SharePoint2010 Html Elements jumps right

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sharepoint-2010

I have cornered my self in a funny little issue in SharePoint2010.

It seems that some HTML Elements suddenly jumps a distance to the right triggered by either Click, Double click or select.

So if an html element is clicked, it suddenly moves to the right, some times allot, sometimes a little. After that it seems fixed...

It also seems to only affect IE, I can't reproduce it in Chrome.

Have anyone experienced something similar and found a fix?

I know this question has no examples etc, but since the HTML and CSS of a SharePoint2010 page is as huge as it is, I figured it wouldn't help a bit,I wouldn't know what snippet to share anyways... I have tried to see if something is added in CSS (Like Margin or something) but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: can you at least describe an html element that you're select/clicking.  Then review the IE Dev Tools if you can capture any JS pubbled events?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are looking for regarding the IE Dev Tools (Im use the the chrome tools) but are we talking "profiling" what happens?... Regarding Elements, next comment ->

Comment: It seems to happen on quite a few elements, but one thing I have noticed. If we take the standard pages used in the edit and view list item dialogs, I can provoke the behavior in an edit dialog, but I cant seem to do the same for a view dialog. as of elements it goes for all Field Descriptions, some input fiels (not richtext areas or datetime it seem), and various elements outside the "edit table". (to call it something) (But I can't say for sure what element beneeth that is affected, as i can't seem to trace any changes to the DOM or styles)

Comment: Do you have custom master page set up for your installation?  If so, have you tried reverting to OOB master and see if the same behavior still occurs?

Comment: With Dev tools, i would try to turn javascript debugger and see if the click triggers any JavaScript code.  You did mention that there are no changes in the DOM that you can see.

Comment: We have a Custom master page yes, and I seem to have narrowed it down to that. Since the behavior persists if I remove all custom styles and scripts.

Comment: Or not... the v4 master page does the same thing...

Comment: Or so I thought... I have a loaded version of a page where the error occurs, then another where it doesn't... The markup are the exact same, our custom CSS is empty for both, no custom scripts...

So either caches are teasing me a bit here, or I think it's safe to say that I can't reproduce it in the V4 master page.

Comment: i am a bit confused.  So under v4.master, the issue does go away. Make sure you remove the cache, of course before testing.  If then, then we need to drill down into the custom.master and control customization that are on it.

Comment: I think so... Must have been something left behind stored in a cache somewhere... Ill be starting over on a "new" master page and see if I can't spot when and where it goes wrong... But that will take some time and I also have a vacation in the middle of it all... So won't be able to fix it over the next 3-4 weeks...

Comment: good luck with the new master page.  starting fresh or from a well known master pages always helps.